# How to get element to element power in two arrays in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays with 3 elements in each.

```
reduction_combs = [2, 3, 7]
elements = [3,6,8]
```

Is there a shortway to compute new array which is :

```
c = [2**3 , 3**6, 7**8]
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved using a simple list comprehension.

```
[x ** y for (x, y) in zip(elements, reduction_combs)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can just do `[x**y for (x,y) in zip(reduction_combs, elements)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use map with lambda expressions passing two lists:

```
c = list(map(lambda x,y: x**y, reduction_combs, elements))
```

Where x and y will be values from reduction_combs and elements, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `zip` method, this is another way using `enumerate` and list comprehension. Here `j` is the element of `reduction_combs` and `i` is the corresponding index using which you fetch the power to be raised from `elements`

```
c = [j**elements[i] for i, j in enumerate(reduction_combs)]
```

Comment: We think alike I posed my answer and scroll up and you did the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 3, 7])
b = np.array([3, 6, 8])

a ** b
# output: array([8, 729,5764801])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the numpy [power](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) function:

```
import numpy as np

reduction_combs = [2, 3, 7]
elements = [3, 6, 8]

print(np.power(reduction_combs, elements))
```

**Output**

```
[      8     729 5764801]
```

If you want the output as a list simply do:

```
np.power(reduction_combs, elements).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either using `numpy`:

```
import numpy
reduction_combs = numpy.array([2, 3, 7])
elements = numpy.array([3, 6, 8])
c = reduction_combs ** elements
```

or if you want to do it with plain python, you might want to consider list comprehension:

```
c = [reduction_combs[i] ** elements[i] for i in range(len(reduction_combs))]
```

You should learn a bit more about what lists do in python and if you often work with arrays, get used to work with numpy!

Answer (score 0):

If you like functional style as an alternative to the excellent [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816939/3620003) proposed by tda, here's a solution with `operator.pow` and `itertools.starmap`.

```
>>> from operator import pow
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> list(starmap(pow, zip(reduction_combs, elements))) 
[8, 729, 5764801]
```

In addition, since you tagged `numpy`, leveraging element-wise vectorized operations makes for a very straight forward solution.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> r = np.array(reduction_combs)
>>> e = np.array(elements)
>>> 
>>> r**e
array([      8,     729, 5764801])
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the quick solution would be:

```
c = [a**b for a,b in zip(reduction_combs, elements)]
```

You can also try using numpy as below:

```
import numpy as np
c = np.power(reduction_combs, elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `enumerate` and `pow`

```
c = [pow(v, elements[i]) for i, v in enumerate(reduction_combs)]
```